# Tabulator: Download Error - No such download type found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabulator

Would like to ask for some help I am currently using **Tabulator** (4.9) along with Vue. I am having trouble downloading/exporting my data to Excel. I have already included **SheetJS** on my project as stated from Tabulator's page.

The following gives me an error that the **XLSX is not defined**:

```
import 'xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js'
this.tabulator.download('xlsx', 'data.xlsx')
```

But once I include the XLSX, then it tells me "**Download Error - No such download type found**":

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js'
this.tabulator.download(XLSX, 'data.xlsx')
```

Would really like to know if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is correct, you should be calling the download function and passing in the `xlsx` string

```js
this.tabulator.download('xlsx', 'data.xlsx');
```

The issue is that Tabulator is expecting to find the XLSX object on the `window` object *(or `global` object if this is a node project)* as that is where the library is put when pulled in from the CDN.

So in you case your import should be:

```js
import XLSX from 'xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js';
window.XLSX = XLSX;
```

Comment: ohhh, will try this as soon as I can! ^^

Comment: hey, was able to test this out and it fixed my issue! thanks! ^^

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried using tabulator. You could look over its documentation again to see if you are missing something. Otherwise, I have used [vue-json-csv](https://github.com/Belphemur/vue-json-csv). You can import it globally and call it anywhere you want to in your templates.

```
 <DownloadCsv :data="exportData" name="export.csv">
  <button class="mr-2">Export to csv</button>
 </DownloadCsv>
```

It takes a `data` prop, which would be the json data set you wish to export to excel. And the `name` prop, this is going to be the name of the export file when it is generated.

Comment: Thanks, will try to look into this as well. But what I basically needed was HTML table to Excel.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address the problem it just introduces another library into the mix